# Why would Visual Studio 2010 say it can't show a variable during debug?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

In **Visual Studio 2010** sometimes when I want to get the **value of a variable** while debugging, it tells me that it "**does not exist in this context**" when it obviously does.

I have found that if I ***use*** the variable, as in the **screenshot** below, then it is able to show it.

Has anyone experienced this? Visual Studio 2008 never did this.

**How can I get Visual Studio 2010 to always show me variable values while debugging?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/jcnr1s.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/jcnr1s.png)

Comment: Dumb question.  The helper method isn't using LINQ is it?

Comment: What language/environment (ASP.NET?) are you debugging?  Did you attach to the process after it had already been running? (The .NET JIT might compile differently when a debugger is not attached).

Comment: *fileNames* gets optimized out because you don't actually do anything with it. When i have used variables in the same fashion (i.e. it is there for debugging purposes only), i follow it with a *Console.Write(fileNames.Count)* (or a Debug.Write) just to ensure it is "used".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hazarding a guess..

Could it be that your running in Release mode and the variable has been optimized out?  Once you actually use the value, then it no longer can optimize the value out?

Comment: Can you even use the debugger in Release mode?

Comment: you bet! Change your build configuration to 'Release' and hit F5 - should still run, though YMMV with optimizations enabled.  I'm only guessing thats what might be whats seen here.

Comment: Far out... your idea seems pretty likely then.

Comment: that was it, I didn't know you could debug in release mode so it didn't occur to me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is GetListOfFileNames() deferring execution? Try tacking .ToList() on it.