# Can't see the variable values while debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would Visual Studio 2010 say it can’t show a variable during debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784678/why-would-visual-studio-2010-say-it-cant-show-a-variable-during-debug)

This happens frequently where I step into a function in c++ and I can't see the value of the variable. In C# I just step in and I can see everything about the object. Is this a known problem or am I doing something wrong.

I want to be able to step into `MethodName(x,y);` and see the x and y values inside the new method.

I am using visual studio 2010

Comment: Did you build on debug mode?

Comment: Did you try to make an unoptimzed debug build with debug symbols?

Comment: Do you mean you can't evaluate the variables ("expression..cannot be evaluated"), or you can't step into MethodName() at all? If you're doing the debug build suggested by others you should be able to see the variables/parameters. If you can't step into MethodName(), maybe you don't have the source? Is MethodName() in a 3rd party library?

Comment: Nick. Please post that as an answer. I finally figured out what the difference is between debug and release mode in VS. Wow. So helpful.

Comment: You know, this is an exact duplicate of the first match that comes up as 'related to this question'. You might've tried investigating those answers first. It auto-fills out that list as you're typing in your question for a reason.